# How to use THREE.CSS3DRenderer in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I have already applied three.js in my angular2 app by npm install both @types/three@0.0.27 and three@0.82.1 and I import them in my service.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
```

but when i try to use CSS3DRenderer,

```
this.renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
```

I got the error

> *core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: THREE.CSS3DRenderer is not a constructor*. It seems like css3drenderer is not in the three.js
>   package.

I also did *npm install css3drenderer*. Now I have both CSS3DRenderer.js in node_modules/css3drenderer/ and three-css3drenderer.d.ts in node_modules/@types/three/

So how could I use new THREE.CSS3DRenderer() in angular2? BTW I have angular2@2.1.2 with webpack. Any advise will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You've obtained the class, but did you add the THREE.CSS3DRenderer js file to the app? Is it loaded before your main script and after three.min.js? if you're making your own min file, is it being minified and included at the correct point?

Comment: @Radio No I didn't add it, neither three.min.js. None of them in my index.html. I just * import * as THREE from "three"; * in my component and I got the THREE in my component. But the CSS3DRenderer is not in the three.js package, so I wish I could use CSS3DRenderer in my component the same way as THREE.webglrenderer, don't have to add css3renderer.min.js in my html, just import the \@types. I think it is possible, just couldn't figure it out. Thank you for your comment, wish more of your advise.

Comment: @mok My solution below should work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit 2 - Example features such as OrbitControls**

Extended features of Three.js such as the examples folder which shows OrbitControls, etc, are not packaged within the main build. Because of this they don't technically exist at runtime as they are not linked to Angular and not compiled into the vendor/build files.

To include these you need to add them manually to the angular.json file. e.g.

https://github.com/marcusbelcher/angular-three-js-composition/blob/master/angular.json

In this file go to project.architect.scripts array and add their node_modules path.

```
"scripts": [
     "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
     "./node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
     "./node_modules/three/examples/controls/OrbitControls.js"
]
```

Notice the difference between build and examples folder. For each extra feature add it's direct path. Also becareful about typing as the typings definition of Three might not include all of the examples thus look at Edit 1 in how to extend this locally.

---

**Edit 1 - Typings**

Since Angular 6 typings.d.ts is no longer created on application creation. This needs to be done inside the app typings inside of the src folder. Please see the following example if you get stuck.

https://github.com/marcusbelcher/angular-three-js-composition

Primarily these two files:
https://github.com/marcusbelcher/angular-three-js-composition/blob/master/src/tsconfig.app.json

https://github.com/marcusbelcher/angular-three-js-composition/blob/master/src/typings.d.ts

Note: I have used type Any here, however this should ideally be an interface, etc.

---

This is dependant on Angular 4 CLI. Also this is a quick solution I needed for a throw away project, nothing long term...

Firstly create a project with the cli and then install Three.JS normally through npm.

If you install the @types/three bindings you should have access to the typical Three.JS objects such as the WebGLRenderer, etc, within a *component.ts. GitHub user Augle-me published the following to do the typescript bindings for a CSS3Renderer: [Link](https://github.com/augle-me/three-renderer-css3d)

However, instead of another 3rd party, I chose the route of adding external global scripts to an Angular CLI project and explicitly declaring the types. The following are my steps in getting something basic rendering:

1. Remove the @types/three types
2. Add "declare var THREE: any;" to typings.d.ts
3. Add the node_module paths to .angular-cli.json

   `"scripts": [
       "../node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
       "../node_modules/three/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"
     ],`
4. Add the following code to a component to create and render a CSS3 scene

   ```
   this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
   this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
   this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1000));
   this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

   this.element = document.createElement('div');
   this.element.innerHTML = 'Plain text inside a div.';
   this.element.className = 'three-div';

   //CSS3D renderer
   this.renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
   this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   this.renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
   this.renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
   //css3SandbboxEl is bound to a div via @ViewChild('css3Sandbox')
   this.css3SandboxEl.nativeElement.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

   this.element3d = new THREE.CSS3DObject(this.element);
   this.element3d.position.x = 50;
   this.element3d.position.y = 50;
   this.element3d.position.z = -1000;
   this.scene.add(this.element3d);
   this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
   ```

Hope this helps.

Marcus

Comment: Hello, I am also trying to use CSS3D, however I am getting error:
THREE.CSS3DObject is not a constructor.

Comment: @qUest Updated my answer inline with the migration guide from Three.js. Use "three.min.js" instead of "three.js" https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: @Marcus, I am using @types/three and importing as import * as THREE from 'three', with THREE I can use scene and perspective camera but I cannot use OrbitControls and few other, I don't why, everything seems good in three/index.d.ts

Comment: @Rishi I updated the above answer for your use case. if you continue to have problems let me know the list of files you need to include and I will try knock up a test case on GitHub.

Comment: @Marcus I'm glad that you've nailed it in Angular, I hope that you also have solution for React: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/16095

Comment: @5ervant Nope, however I'll have a bash this weekend! Whats your React setup like? creat-react-app v2, TS?

Comment: @Marcus `create-react-app` es6, I'm now using `npm i three-css3drenderer`.

Comment: @5ervant My main aim is to not use `npm i three-css3drenderer` but only `npm i three`. 

Currently I haven't found a proper solution which doesn't involve ejecting. I currently have a temp solution linked below which:

- Via ncp copies files to the public folder and references them in the head
- Declare THREE as (window.THREE) to stop `Attempted import error: 'CSS3DObject' is not exported from 'three' (imported as 'THREE')` errors
- Three.JS is bundled twice :-/

Code: https://github.com/marcusbelcher/create-react-app-three-js/tree/feature/css

Will update when I relook at this!

Comment: FYI above doesn't meet your requirement on Webpack typing checks. I just hacked around it to get a demo "working".